# WinRT - Get all controls from codebehind

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

In certain matters I need all my controls to be set as ReadOnly.

All of my controls have a x:Name directive and its being used in order to set for each control.

Well when the Page starts to have a little more controls it becomes ineffective in my opinion to specify for each control that is readonly.

Is there a way to say in the code behind of the xmal that all controls are readonly or atleast the controls which are based on the same class.

Answer (score 0):

The visual tree contains all logical elements including all visual elements of the template of each element. The visual tree is responsible for **Propagate the IsEnabled** property, So you can set IsEnabled property of your Page to false value and see all of child control will disabled. And not necessary to set this property for all control on the page.

Comment: I tried your solution but what I need is not the whole page to be disabled since I have navigation in it. I need only the controls in the page.

Comment: @MartinZPetrov, So i recommended to use a style in resource of page that target type is baseclass that you want and set IsEnabled to false.

Comment: You can also just change the IsEnabled of a Panel that contains your controls (like LayoutRoot or suche). Just make sure you have all controls you want to disable in one Panel and disabled it there.